# CopyTo with CancellationToken argument

Tags: c#, .net, cancellation-token

I see `CopyToAsync` has `CancellationToken` argument. But I don't need `CopyToAsync` as my code is already executed in background thread. I just want to have `CopyTo` overload which takes `CancellationToken` and checks it every time it copies bufferSize amount of bytes. Is there any built in implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just taken .NET CopyTo implementation and added one line in the cycle:

```
public static void CopyTo(this Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int count;
    while ((count = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
}
```

But I find it disappointing .NET Framework designers don't care about cancellation of long-running synchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

I may say that the built-in implementation is `CopyToAsync` with CancellationToken.

In my opinion you will spend less time implementing `CopyToAsync` (instead of `CopyTo`) than building your own implementation of Cancellation (and less risk of errors/bugs).

Comment: That's how I have it done for now. But I don't like the idea of creating a new thread and waiting for it...

Comment: You can find implementation examples of `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource` here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx

Comment: you create a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass the `CancellationTokenSource.Token` to your background working thread and check for `token.IsCancellationRequested` every time you read a chunk of your file, don't forget to clean your resources in case of Cancellation

Answer (score 0):

For the case that no better answer arrives: You can implement a synchronous copy loop with 10 lines of C# as a reusable helper method. Take a peek with Reflector how this is done.